# What happened to the Chrome FPS meter?

Tags: google-chrome, frame-rate

I'm struggling to show FPS in the current version of Chrome, Version 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit). If I open the window that I always used to open (using the Rendering tab), I get this:

[image]

I've tried clicking it, but it doesn't change what it displays. What's going on here? Did they remove this?

Answer (score 0):

they remove this:
https://twitter.com/ben_a_adams/status/1281498730726744065

completely removing the FPS counter